# Ubuntu 12.04 get stucked on boot (ubuntu logo + mouse cursor)

Tags: 12.04, boot

After running the latest update on my Thinkpad running Ubuntu 12.04 i got the kernel `3.5.0-44-generic`. After rebooting, the system stucks at the "Ubuntu Loading Screen" (with the dots) and shows the mouse cursor, which cant be moved. I use Gnome 3 and Autologin, but when i try to switch to another login (via <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) nothing happens as well.

When I hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> during boot, i see 2 messages that appear strange to me:

```
* Stopping GNOME Display Manager [OK]
* Stopping save kernel messages [OK]
```

(no fail here)

I can start the recovery-mode. But how to fix this...?

Comment: It's empty in recovery mode. Do i have to enable something to get log entries?

Comment: Well, then, post that as your own answer below, click on the checkmark, and show others it worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed it on my own. The problem was most likely related to Steam. I added the x-swat ppa few days ago (as suggested by Steam). After removing it (and removing all related packages), problems are gone.

1. Started in Recovery Mode
2. Repair Packages (to get file system mounted read+write)
3. Activate Network
4. Run following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   ```
5. Reboot